# Error installing Pygame / Python 3.4.1

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to install Pygame and it returns me the following error "Python version 3.4 required which was not found in the registry". However I already have the Python 3.4.1 installed on my system. Does anyone know how to solve that problem? 
I've been using Windows 8.1
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a 64-bit operating system? Try using the 32-bit installer.

Comment: That's a good tip. I'm using a 64-bit operating system but I installed the 32-bit version without paying attention. Obviously the 32-bit installer worked like a charm! So pay attention in case you guys committed the same mistake as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Tips I can provide:

1. Add Python to your Path file in the Advanced settings of your Environmental Variables (just search for it in the control panel)
2. Something may have gone wrong with the download of Python, so re-install it. Also don't download the 64-bit version, just download the 32-bit version from the main pygame website
3. Once that's sorted out, transfer the entire Pygame file to the site packages in the Python directory and open up the pygame file and go to this directory in command prompt. Finally, run the Pygame setup from the command prompt which should be something like:

   python setup.py

But this will only work if the pygame setup file is called setup.py (it's been a while since I downloaded it), you added Python to the Path file and you're currently in the correct directory in command prompt.

To test if it worked try importing pygame and see if you got an error or not.